# Writing files out to disk with names that incorporate a parameter value

Tags: export, files-and-directories

I have a notebook I run for different values of aspect ratio A all integers except 2.5 and copies its  multiple plot results to my hard disc. So when I change A and rerun it, I have to manually change all the file output names to avoid getting the existing results for the previous A overwritten. This is time consuming and mistake prone. What is the syntax for a file name that say has a numerical ending of the current value ot A please?

Comment: `"fileName"<>TextString[NumberForm[A,{1,1}]]<>".txt"` or 
`A = 2.2; `
`"fileName" <> StringReplace[#, "." -> "_"] &@
  TextString[NumberForm[A, {1, 1}]] <> ".txt"`

Comment: Nice one, @RolfMertig I always like to make anonymous functions for this type of thing. Something like: `"filehead-"<>ToString[#]&<>"-"<>ToString[A]<>".extail"/@Range@10`

Comment: @simon Why don't you paste your export command?

Comment: Try `Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "eflut3i.tiff"}], out]`

Comment: Sorry where does the integer A enter in the name to replace my specific value of 3?

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the commented example (it is wise to update your post with such things, for future reference) one would do something like the following:

```
A=3;
out[A_,function_]:=outfunc[A,function];
(*where outfunc[arg, argfunc] is the function based on arg and argfunc one would like to export*)

outexporter[A_,function_,driveletter_]:=outexporter[A,function,driveletter]=Export[ToString[driveletter]<>":\\"<>ToString[function]<>ToString[A]<>"i.tiff", out[A,function],Resolution -> 300]
```

Hope this helps! Please, let me know if I can explain anything to ya? :D!

Comment: @simon thank you for the kind words! I use this method in my normal workflows where I inevitably use it to make files which have dependencies of 8-10 variables that can change, & it works like a charm. The trick is to weave together various combinations of `ToString[varID]` and just plain-old `varString` if you’re setting options with atoms. `<>` is the shortcut for `StringJoin[]` and you’ll find that if you keep a consistent data structure, you can make custom `Import` and `Export` functions that are evaluated purely by your variable inputs. So I just copy and paste the same inputs for each!

Comment: @simon nice! So then, this method should work for you! What do you have so far? I’m not sure what you mean by the “internal Mathematica graph name”, nor the “stub output name” but most everything else should be easily achieved with minor modifications to my answer :)

Comment: @simon I’m not sure what you mean or are asking? You should make re a function of A by simply adding `[A_]:` between `re` and `=`. Then, having done this, you will call `re[A]` instead of whatever other function you may want to call. So in the end you have `re` used instead of function when you run `outexporter` and then `outfunc==re`. Ie `out[A,re]` evaluates the output used in `outexporter[A,re,C]` that gives you the desired  effects!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100124/discussion-between-ca-trevillian-and-simon).

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`StringTemplate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html).

For values of some parameter.

```
tFilename = StringTemplate["AValueAt`1`.gif"];
tFilename /@ {1, 2, 2.5, 3}
```

> ```
> {"AValueAt1.gif", "AValueAt2.gif", "AValueAt2.5.gif", "AValueAt3.gif"}
> ```

You can also include the plot result name.

```
tFilename2 = StringTemplate["Step`1`_AValueAt`2`.gif"];
tFilename2 @@@ {{"One", 1}, {"Two", 2.5}, {"Three", 3}}
```

> ```
> {"StepOne_AValueAt1.gif", "StepTwo_AValueAt2.5.gif", "StepThree_AValueAt3.gif"}
> ```

`StringTemplate` can also use named slots with `Association`.

```
tFilename3 = StringTemplate["Step`StepName`_AValueAt`Value`.gif"];
tFilename3@<|"StepName" -> "Association", "Value" -> 4|>
```

> ```
> "StepAssociation_AValueAt4.gif"
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Credit to CA Trevillian, the short simple answer I wanted which works is

```
Export["c:/.graph#"<>ToString[A]<>".tiff", out, ImageResolution -> 300]
```

where `<>ToString[A]<>` is the sought insertion for the numerical value of `A`.

Comment: I don't think this is a "thank you" post. I see it as a self-answer where the OP acknowledges the help received from CA Trevillian..

Comment: Well, my answer was originally accepted but then unaccepted, my intention was to provide a general method with functional approach && I managed that! I hoped OP was able to understand how they could use it, and, I *think* they landed at a comprehension in the end. Without a functional approach to your project notebook, if one is just setting the A variable, then this would work. You can also, of course, just insert the global A into the format I & others provided! As to which is better, is up to the use case, I think.